# How could I skip drawing empty/zero value and its value on tooltip

Tags: chart.js

I want to skip some points with `zero value` on line chart of `chartjs`.

How could I do it ?

## expected result

[image]

[image]

## sampledata

```
    :labels => [
    [ 0] "10/01 (Thu)",
    [ 1] "10/02 (Fri)",
    [ 2] "10/03 (Sat)",
    [ 3] "10/04 (Sun)",
    [ 4] "10/05 (Mon)",
    [ 5] "10/06 (Tue)",
    [ 6] "10/07 (Wed)",
    [ 7] "10/08 (Thu)",
    [ 8] "10/09 (Fri)",
    [ 9] "10/10 (Sat)",
    [10] "10/11 (Sun)",
    [11] "10/12 (Mon)",
    [12] "10/13 (Tue)",
    [13] "10/14 (Wed)",
    [14] "10/15 (Thu)",
    [15] "10/16 (Fri)",
    [16] "10/17 (Sat)",
    [17] "10/18 (Sun)",
    [18] "10/19 (Mon)",
    [19] "10/20 (Tue)",
    [20] "10/21 (Wed)",
    [21] "10/22 (Thu)",
    [22] "10/23 (Fri)",
    [23] "10/24 (Sat)",
    [24] "10/25 (Sun)",
    [25] "10/26 (Mon)",
    [26] "10/27 (Tue)",
    [27] "10/28 (Wed)",
    [28] "10/29 (Thu)",
    [29] "10/30 (Fri)",
    [30] "10/31 (Sat)",
    [31] "11/01 (Sun)"
]

{
           :label => "Sample1(14:35)",
        :data => [
            [ 0] 5098.0,
            [ 1] 5098.0,
            [ 2] 5098.0,
            [ 3] 3898.0,
            [ 4] 4498.0,
            [ 5] 0,
            [ 6] 5898.0,
            [ 7] 5898.0,
            [ 8] 6698.0,
            [ 9] 6698.0,
            [10] 3898.0,
            [11] 4498.0,
            [12] 4498.0,
            [13] 4498.0,
            [14] 5898.0,
            [15] 7698.0,
            [16] 5098.0,
            [17] 4498.0,
            [18] 5898.0,
            [19] 3398.0,
            [20] 3398.0,
            [21] 3898.0,
            [22] 3398.0,
            [23] 3898.0,
            [24] 0,
            [25] 0,
            [26] 0,
            [27] 0,
            [28] 0,
            [29] 0,
            [30] 0,
            [31] 0
        ],

           :label => "Sample1(14:35)",
        :data => [
            [ 0] 5098.0,
            [ 1] 5098.0,
            [ 2] 5098.0,
            [ 3] 3898.0,
            [ 4] 4498.0,
            [ 5] 6698.0,
            [ 6] 5898.0,
            [ 7] 0,
            [ 8] 0,
            [ 9] 0,
            [10] 3898.0,
            [11] 4498.0,
            [12] 4498.0,
            [13] 4498.0,
            [14] 5898.0,
            [15] 7698.0,
            [16] 5098.0,
            [17] 4498.0,
            [18] 5898.0,
            [19] 3398.0,
            [20] 3398.0,
            [21] 3898.0,
            [22] 3398.0,
            [23] 3898.0,
            [24] 0,
            [25] 0,
            [26] 0,
            [27] 0,
            [28] 0,
            [29] 0,
            [30] 0,
            [31] 0
        ],
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add a text "N/A" instead "0" values in your data:

```
data: ["7", "25", "75", "78", "10", "N/A", "77", "02", "44", "N/A"]
```

this is the result: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qiDv.png)

here is an example: [codepen example](https://codepen.io/Abraxas666/pen/vYKoRvy)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onAnimationComplete function to disable points and tooltip display

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
    animation: false,
    onAnimationComplete: function () {
        // prevents the update from triggering an infinite loop
        if (!this.clearCycle) {
            this.clearCycle = true;

            this.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
                dataset.points.forEach(function (point) {
                    if (point.value === 0) {
                        point.display = false;
                        point.hasValue = function () {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                })
            })

            this.update();
        }
        else
            delete this.clearCycle;
    }
});
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/u7dsy6ep/

---

If you are using animation, the logic needs to be moved to the onAnimationProgress and executed only once, unless you don't mind seeing the dots while the animation is in progress.

Comment: I found a workable [solution here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2119#issuecomment-198817261)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it was possible with previous versions of Chart.js 2, for the tooltips just add this property to Chart object:

```
filter: x => return x.yLabel > 0
```

A simple one liner.
I know it's old, but people might be still confused.

Comment: Where do you bind the filter property.

Answer (score 0):

To hide these values from your tooltip on your chart object, options -> plugins -> tooltip -> filter accepts a function that returns a boolean to render the tooltip.

[github](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/types/index.esm.d.ts#L2611)

```
filter: (e: TooltipItem<TType>, index: number, array: TooltipItem<TType>[], data: ChartData) => boolean;
```

TooltipItem has a `raw` attribute which represents the data value.

in my case this is what my filter function looks like

```
filter: (label) => {
            if (typeof (label.raw) === "number")
              return label.raw > 0
            else return true
          }
```